# RSA Decryption from samples

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

I am working on a project for a client which involves decryption of data which was encrypted using RSA.

The system in question retains three independent copies of each data-set, but each copy is encrypted with a different key. In this scenario, all of the private keys are gone and i want to know if anyone knows of a methodology to use the three encrypted copies of the data (which are identical - no padding) to determine the original data-set.

Any help/thoughts/comments would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the public exponent? If e=3 decryption is simple (see Watson's answer). If e is bigger than the number of copies, this attack shouldn't work. But lack of proper padding (preferably OAEP) is still a very bad idea.

Comment: See [Dan Boneh - Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/abstracts/RSAattack-survey.html) Section 4.2 Hastad's Broadcast Attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem I can compute $M^3$, and then take the cube root. This is why multiple recipient RSA is insecure.

Comment: Thanks guys - this gives me somewhere to start. I'm sure i will be back..